# How can I show a picture on a form in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, vba

I am creating questionnaires using VB.NET and SQL and my problem now is how can I show an image already present in the database onto a form? Please note that as the form is a questionnaire, it is navigable by the means of going up or down rows in a dataset. For example when the NEXT button is clicked, the row in the dataset goes +1. So how should I go about coding it in order to display an image onto the form?

this is the code how i saved the image

```
Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, PictureBox1.Image.RawFormat)
Dim data As Byte() = ms.GetBuffer()
Dim x As New SqlParameter("@image", SqlDbType.Image)
x.Value = data
cmd.Parameters.Add(x)
```

And the code for navigating between rows of a dataset in a single form:

```
RichTextBox1.Text = dsquestionnaire.Tables(0).Rows(qsno).Item("Question") .....

qsno + 1 (As a part of the NEXT button click event)
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please see code that displays the information while navigating.

Comment: here function for create image from bytes http://stackoverflow.com/a/9388682/1271037 But I recommend you save the address, not the image itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the image from the DB into your picture box as follows:

```
Using ms As New IO.MemoryStream(CType(row("image", Byte()))

Dim img As Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
Image1.Image = img
```

For the click event you can place this inside a method and just call it to load the image into the Picture box when the next button is clicked